# Problem with reading inertia values from sdf in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there, I have a problem with defining inertia in the model sdf file. Everything is as in the code below, but when I import the model into Gazebo, it seems as if the program disregards everything in the intertial tags and inserts its own values. Is there something very obvious that I am missing?

[image: image description]

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version="1.4">
<model name="Mymodel">
    <pose>0 0 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
    <static>true</static>
        <link name="body">
            <inertial>
                <mass>0.002</mass>
                <inertia>
                    <ixx>0.000000420478</ixx> 
                    <ixy>0.0</ixy>         
                    <ixz>0.0</ixz>         
                    <iyy>0.000000091134</iyy>      
                    <iyz>0.0</iyz>        
                    <izz>0.000000404044</izz>      
                </inertia>
            </inertial>
            <collision name="collision">
                <geometry>
                    <box>
                        <size>0.015 0.047 0.018</size>
                    </box>
                </geometry>
             </collision>
             <visual name="visual">
                <geometry>
                   <mesh>
                       <uri>model:///mymodel/meshes/mymodel.stl</uri>
                   </mesh>
                </geometry>
             </visual>
      </link>
</model>
</sdf>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17057/problem-with-reading-inertia-values-from-sdf-in-gazebo/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's actually fine. Gazebo has some limit decimal numbers.

If you load your model using gazebo GUI and enter the edit model feature.
You can see that the inertial and mass are just as you specified
[image: image description]

To reassure, you can try changing the number in SDF with higher number such as 5, then you can see that it actually matches the one you see in GUI.

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2835/alienmon/) with karma: 28 on 2017-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1